# Transforming the solutions of $\dot x = f(\mathbf{x}, t)$ and $\dot x = B(\mathbf{x}, t)f(\mathbf{x}, t)$ into each other

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

How can I prove the following theorem?

If the function $B(\mathbf{x}, t)$ is strictly positive, then the solutions of the two differential equations $\dot x = f(\mathbf{x}, t)$ and $\dot x = B(\mathbf{x}, t)f(\mathbf{x}, t)$ can be transformed into each other by a strictly monotonic change in the time scale $\tau = \phi(t)$.

**Note:** This theorem is mentioned in Hofbauer and Sigmund's *Evolutionary Games and Population Dynamics*, p. 32.

---

Here is what I got so far, but I'm not sure how to proceed:
\begin{align*}
  \frac{d \mathbf{x}}{d \tau} &= B(\mathbf{x}(\tau),
                                    \tau)f(\mathbf{x}(\tau), \tau) \\
  \frac{d \mathbf{x}}{d t}\frac{dt}{d\tau} &=
                                                       B(\mathbf{x}(\tau), \tau)f(\mathbf{x}(\tau), \tau) \\
 f(\mathbf{x},t) \frac{dt}{d \tau} &=
  B(\mathbf{x}(\tau), \tau)f(\mathbf{x}(\tau), \tau) \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Hm. It's strange, but I'm aware of only autonomous case of this theorem.

Comment: Do you know where I can find the proof for the autonomous case?

Comment: You almost did it by yourself :) In case of autonomous system $f(\mathbf{x}, t)$ and $f(\mathbf{x}(\tau), \tau)$ are the same (vector field doesn't depend on time; the point of phase space is the same for both expressions) and you can easily find $t(\tau)$ from its derivative.

Comment: And I guess in the autonomous case B(x) doesn't have to be strictly positive, does it?

Comment: No, even in autonomous case it has to have strict sign. There are two reasons for this: 1) technical: convergence of integral that defines $t(\tau)$; 2) methodical: you don't want to create additional equilibrium points, because this will clearly made two system 'not the same', right?